# Model parallelism in TensorFlow multi-gpu training

Tags: tensorflow

I am training a model in several GPUs on a single machine using tensorflow. However, I find the speed is much slower than training on a single GPU. I am wondering if tensorflow executes sub-model in different GPUs in parallel or in a sequential order. For example:

```
x = 5
y = 2
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
     z1 = tf.multiply(x, y)
with tf.device('/gpu:1'):
     z2 = tf.add(x, y)
```

Are the code inside `/gpu:0` and `/gpu:1` executes sequentially? If in sequential order, how can I make the two parts execute in parallel? Assume the two parts are not dependent on each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TensorFlow only the second block (inside gpu:1) would execute since nothing depends on the first block.

Comment: So if the blocks are not dependent, then they will execute in parallel. Is this correct?

Comment: If they are not dependent they will execute in parallel, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is executing sequentially, by its nature the with block will wait till its computation is complete before moving to next code block.

You can implement queues and threading from tensorflow to leverage your additional compute.

Please refer thsi tutorial from tensorflow:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/threading_and_queues